# Why is Pandas' whitespace delimiter skipping one of my values?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, whitespace

I'm currently trying to use Python read a **text file** into Sqlite3 using Pandas. Here are a few entries from the text file:

```
1  Michael  462085  2.2506  Jessica  302962  1.5436
2  Christopher  361250  1.7595  Ashley  301702  1.5372
3  Matthew  351477  1.7119  Emily  237133  1.2082
```

T**he data consists of popular baby names, and I have to separate male names and female names into their own tables and perform queries on them.** My method consists of first placing all the data into both tables, then dropping the unneeded columns afterwards. **My issue is that when I try to add names to the columns, I get a value error: The expected axis has 6 elements, but 7 values. I'm assuming it's because Pandas possibly isn't reading the last values of each line, but I can't figure out how to fix it. My current delimiter is a whitespace delimiter that you can see below.**

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect("C:\\****\\****\\****\\****\\****\baby_names.db")
c=con.cursor()


# Please note that most of these functions will be commented out, because they will only be run once.

def create_and_insert():
    # load data
    df = pd.read_csv('babynames.txt', index_col=0, header=None, sep= '\s+', engine = 'python')
    # Reading the textfile

    df.columns = ['Rank', 'BoyName', 'Boynumber', 'Boypercent', 'Girlname', 'Girlnumber', 'Girlpercent']
    # Adding Column names

    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()


    con = sqlite3.connect("*************\\baby_names.db")

    # drop data into database
    df.to_sql("Combined", con)

    df.to_sql("Boys", con)

    df.to_sql("Girls", con)

    con.commit()
    con.close()
create_and_insert()

def test():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Boys WHERE Rank = 1")
    print(c.fetchall())






test()



con.commit()
con.close()
```

I've tried adding multiple delimiters, but it didn't seem to do anything. Using just regular space as the delimiter seems to just create 'blank' column names. From reading the Pandas docs, it says that multiple delimiters are possible, but I can't quite figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try read_csv with ``sep='\s+'`` more than one space.

Comment: When I add a space on either side (' \s+ ') nothing changes. If I add two spaces on any side, it says axis = 0.

Comment: I've also tried using a | to separate both space and the whitespace RE. That makes it so there are 12 axis values, but only 7 names.

Comment: I've also tried getting rid of one of the column names so the axis and names "match up", but it's still not returning any column names when I perform a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- your input file contains **7** columns,
- but the initial column is set as the **index** (you passed *index_col=0*),
- so your DataFrame contains only **6** regular columns.

Print *df* to confirm it.

Now, when you run `df.columns = ['Rank', ...]`, you attempt to assing the
**7** passed names to existing **6** data columns.

Probably you should:

- read the DataFrame without setting the index (for now),
- assign all 7 column names,
- set *Rank* column as the index.

The code to do it is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('babynames.txt', header=None, sep='\s+', engine='python')
df.columns = ['Rank', 'BoyName', 'Boynumber', 'Boypercent', 'Girlname', 'Girlnumber',
    'Girlpercent']
df.set_index('Rank', inplace=True)
```

Or even shorter (all in one):

```
df = pd.read_csv('babynames.txt', sep='\s+', engine='python',
    names=['Rank', 'BoyName', 'Boynumber', 'Boypercent', 'Girlname', 'Girlnumber',
    'Girlpercent'], index_col='Rank')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! When I previously tried passing the names using the 'names' argument before, nothing happened, but adding the 'index_col' argument worked!